# A man whirls bola

Tags: physics

The bola is a traditional weapon used for tripping up or grounding an animal (Fig). Once it is set into motion, each ball at the end of the bola can be thought of as a single object in uniform circular motion. Suppose it takes the bola 0.3250 s to traverse a circular path with a radius of 0.8661 m. What is the magnitude of the centripetal acceleration experienced by either ball at the end of the bola?
FIGURE. A bola is spun in a circle above the hunter, eventually being released and thrown forward.
I thought it has two centripetal force for this question,but I couldn't figure out how to do it

[image]

Comment: Don't bolas have three balls?

Comment: Also, the millisecond and millimeter accuracy seem exaggerated when air resistance, gravity (weight of the strings - catenoidal shape!), are being neglected

Comment: I thought it has rope tension and the gravity of bola itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a=\omega^2r=\frac{v^2} r=\frac{4\pi^2r}{t^2} .$$